# Angular reactive form search elements

Tags: angular, search, angular-reactive-forms

I need your help. I am trying to search for elements: alive and on the button to search in lower and upper case. `elementsArray` is my array of elements, which consists of fields: `id`, `name`, `price`. This code doesn't give me any errors, but the search doesn't work correctly: it's empty at first, there are no items. When I enter data in input, nothing is shown either, however when I delete all the values, the array elements appear. Tell me, what is my mistake? How to make a live search and by button? Thank you very much

html

```
<form [formGroup]="liveForm">
   <input (input)="findElementsByName()" formControlName="findLiveElement">
</form>

<form [formGroup]="simpleForm">
   <input formControlName="findSimpleElement">
   <button>Find</button>
</form>

<div>
   <p *ngFor="let element of filteredElements">Name: {{element.name}}, price: {{element.price}}</p>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {elementsArray} from "../../array";
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-search',
   templateUrl: './search.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

   public filteredElements: any[] = [];
   elements = elementsArray;
   liveForm: FormGroup;
   simpleForm: FormGroup;

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.liveForm = new FormGroup({
       findLiveElement: new FormControl('')
     })
     this.simpleForm = new FormGroup({
       findSimpleElement: new FormControl('')
     })
    }

   findElementsByName() {
    this.liveForm.controls['findLiveElement'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     this.filteredElements = this.elements;
     this.filteredElements = this.elements.filter(
      element => element.name.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      element.name.toUpperCase().includes(value));
     })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="simpleForm">
   <input formControlName="findSimpleElement">
   <button  (click)="search()">Find</button>
</form>


    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {elementsArray} from "../../array";
    import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

    @Component({
       selector: 'app-search',
       templateUrl: './search.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
    })

    export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

       public filteredElements: any[] = [];
       elements = elementsArray;
       liveForm: FormGroup;
       simpleForm: FormGroup;

       ngOnInit(): void {
         this.liveForm = new FormGroup({
           findLiveElement: new FormControl('')
         })
         this.simpleForm = new FormGroup({
           findSimpleElement: new FormControl('')
         })
         this.filteredElements=elements;
        }

      search() {
        this.filterTeredElements(
          this.simpleForm.controls['findSimpleElement'].value
        );
      }

      filterTeredElements(value) {
        this.filteredElements = this.elements.filter(
          (element) =>
            element.name.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
            element.name.toUpperCase().includes(value)
        );
      }

      findElementsByName() {
        this.liveForm.controls['findLiveElement'].valueChanges.subscribe(
          (value) => {
            this.filterTeredElements(value);
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works, but it's a little strange. When writing the value to `input`, it filters the items correctly for me. HOWEVER, it filters in such a way that if you enter more than 2-4 characters, just like from the product name, all the items are missing, or it doesn't even search for the items correctly at all. `It is due to toLowerCase and toUpperCase methods` Why does it work like that, how to search for elements without regard to lowercase and uppercase letters?